# PyCharm with remote interpreter is not showing docstring for 3rd party libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm setting up PyCharm to work with remote interpreter, but in any case I can't get code completion and I can't see docstring. Should I forget some configs or is it normal?

[image: Code completion works]

[image: Code completion doesn't work]

[image: DocString code reference doesn't work]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve that problems.

**Code completion in pyspark module:**

- Editing /etc/sudoers on server: `Defaults    !requiretty`
- Reinstalling pyspark on server with conda: `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark=2.2.0`

**DocString popup error:**

- Just add a local Python interpreter (I have Anaconda on local machine): Settings -> Project Interpreter -> (gear option) -> Conda Environment